# Distribute multiple items with different widths evenly on an menu

Tags: css, menu

I have been trying to find a solution to a common problem but due to some CSS rules in my code I can't use any of the solutions that I have found. I have an horizontal menu (a `<ul> <li> <a>`) with different items, with different widths and I am not able to distribute the items inside the menu so they have the same space between each other. This is the code:

```
<nav id="main-menu">
     <ul class="child-menu">
         <li class="menu-1"><a>outsourcing tecnologico</a></li>
         <li class="menu-2"><a>seleccion de personal</a></li>
         <li class="menu-3"><a>solucion integral de nuevos profesionales</a></li>
         <li class="menu-4"><a>consultoria</a></li>
         <li class="menu-5"><a>formacion especializada</a></li>
         <li class="menu-6"><a>I+D+I<a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS :

```
#main-menu {
    background-color:#000;
    position:relative;
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
    width:980px;
    height:28px;
    float:left;
}

#main-menu ul {
width:980px;
margin:0;
}

#main-menu ul li {
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
}

#main-menu ul li a {
display:block;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:27px;
height:28px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: do you purposefuly create `<li>` without closing tag?

Comment: Is there any special reason why you want to float `#main-menu`?

Comment: Will your menu have only links `<a>` tags, or nested menus?

Comment: sorry i edit the code, now is good. The menu wont have nested menus. I have to float #main-menu due to some issues on liferay.

Comment: What about the `<a>` tags? Can you put those in? These may affect the look and feel of the layout and design.

Comment: ugg done marc, sorry guys.

Comment: What do you want to do with very long labels? If the labels are long enough, the menu could wrap into more than one line.  How would want to deal with that?

Comment: i cant change the labels (yep is that kind of client) so i just have to deal with really long labels

Answer (score 1):

If less than ie ver 9.0 is not required, then following will be useful:

1. Flex box property.
2. 2.`ul { display:table; }  ul li { display:table-cell; text-align:center }`

Comment: `display: table` works in IE8.  Adding demos would go a long way towards supporting your answers (see:  http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/)

Answer (score 0):

don't use float left on the li's rather use display inline-block and *display: inline hack for IE with a zoom: 1; you can then add margins to the li's to keep the spacing the same. center the content with text-align center on the parent element that has a width allocated to it.

Comment: Almost there Gavin, i will let you know if this works asap, many thanks.

Comment: just take the width off your #main-menu ul as well it is not necessary

Comment: #main-menu {
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    margin:10px 0 0;
    width:980px;
    height:28px;
    float:left;
}

#main-menu ul {
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

#main-menu ul li {
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom:1;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
}

#main-menu ul li a {
display:block;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:28px;
height:28px;
text-align:center;
}

Comment: Everything is working just fine, now the menu is centered inside the #main-menu BUT i want the hover of the first item of the menu to be on the left extreme of the #main-menu div and the hover of last item of the menu on the right extreme. Apparently i cant do that with just giving the <li>'s a right margin because the firs and last items margins are different.

Comment: if you are not going to change the width of the containing parent you could always add padding to the ancor tag elements until it fills up your entire containing element. you then use the pseudo class :first-child and :last-child to remove the margins left and right respectively from the first and last anchortag element.

Comment: Hey Gavin i just wanna thank you for your solution, finally it worked really nice. Also sorry for my late reply i was pretty busy at work, all the best !

Answer (score 0):

**A Partial Solution**

I have a solution that may be a good start:

```
#main-menu {
    background-color:#000;
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:1080px;
    height:28px;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.child-menu  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}
.child-menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.child-menu a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

With a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Tp7wH/

**Some Design Issues and Questions**

If you fix the width of the `main-menu`, you will see some space on the far left and far right.

When I set the width to 980px, the links wrapped into a second line.  You need to think about this.

I display the `ul` and `li` elements as inline, but you could also use inline blocks if you want a more button-like look to the menu.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to add additional empty li elements between menu items just for spacing. This solution works well if the number of horizontal menu items is known in advance. It also allows the first item to touch the left edge of the containing element and last item to touch the right edge. The menu items will not be wrapped or rearranged when window is made smaller.

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">First Item</a></li><li class="space"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a></li><li class="space"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bah</a></li><li class="space"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Last one is long</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs{
    display:table;
    width:500px;
}
.tabs li{
    display:table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.space {
    width: 33%; /* This should be 100 / (nr of elements - 1) */
}
```

Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LqLE9/